# Trying to use pixels to draw on two different canvases

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, canvas, pixel

I'm trying to create two canvases (420px by 420px) and use pixels to draw on both of them.

One will have four horizontal stripes that are different colors, and the other will have just one color, but the same size as the four stripes together (400px by 400px).

However, only the canvas with stripes show. The one-color canvas doesn't. Please help .

Here's the code:

````
<body>
  
  <canvas id="Canvas1" width="420" height="420" style="border:3px solid black"></canvas>
  <canvas id="Canvas2" width="420" height="420" style="border:3px solid black"></canvas>
  
<script>
  var c = document.getElementById("Canvas1");
  var c1 = document.getElementById("Canvas2");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var ctx1 = c1.getContext("2d");
var width =400; var height =400;
var imgData = ctx.createImageData(width, height);
var imgData1 = ctx1.createImageData(width, height);
for(var y = 0; y<400; y++){
 for(var x=0; x<400; x++){
 var i = (x+y*width)*4;

  for (i = 0; i < imgData1.data.length; i += 4) {
       imgData.data[i+0] = 0;
       imgData.data[i+1] = 0;
       imgData.data[i+2] = 255;
       imgData.data[i+3] = 255;
   }     

  for (i = 0; i < imgData.data.length; i += 4) {
       imgData.data[i+0] = 0;
       imgData.data[i+1] = 0;
       imgData.data[i+2] = 255;
       imgData.data[i+3] = 255;
   }   

  for (i = 0; i < imgData.data.length*3/4; i += 4) {
       imgData.data[i+0] = 0;
       imgData.data[i+1] = 255;
       imgData.data[i+2] = 0;
       imgData.data[i+3] = 255;
   }

  for (i = 0; i < imgData.data.length/2; i += 4) {
       imgData.data[i+0] = 255;
       imgData.data[i+1] = 0;
       imgData.data[i+2] = 0;
       imgData.data[i+3] = 255;
   }

     for (i = 0; i < imgData.data.length/4; i += 4) {
       imgData.data[i+0] = 255;
       imgData.data[i+1] = 0;
       imgData.data[i+2] = 255;
       imgData.data[i+3] = 255;
   }  
 }
}
  
ctx.putImageData(imgData, 10, 10);
</script> 
</body>
</html>```
````

Comment: Which part of your code did you assume would draw anything on `ctx1`?

Answer (score 1):

I see two issues

- In your for loop:
  `for (i = 0; i < imgData1.data.length; i += 4) {`
  you have the `imgData1` but then adding to the `imgData`
- You missed the putImageData into the ctx1:
  `ctx1.putImageData(imgData1`

Here is a sample working code, I did remove some of your code to keep it short:

```js
var c = document.getElementById("Canvas1");
var c1 = document.getElementById("Canvas2");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var ctx1 = c1.getContext("2d");

var imgData = ctx.createImageData(c.width, c.height);
var imgData1 = ctx1.createImageData(c1.width, c1.height);

for (i = 0; i < imgData1.data.length; i += 28) {
  imgData1.data[i + 0] = 200;
  imgData1.data[i + 1] = 0;
  imgData1.data[i + 2] = 200;
  imgData1.data[i + 3] = 200;
}
for (i = 0; i < imgData.data.length; i += 4) {
  imgData.data[i + 0] = 0;
  imgData.data[i + 1] = 0;
  imgData.data[i + 2] = 255;
  imgData.data[i + 3] = 255;
}
for (i = 0; i < imgData.data.length / 2; i += 4) {
  imgData.data[i + 0] = 0;
  imgData.data[i + 1] = 255;
  imgData.data[i + 2] = 0;
  imgData.data[i + 3] = 255;
}

ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
ctx1.putImageData(imgData1, 0, 0);
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 3px solid black
}
```

```html
<canvas id="Canvas1" width="50" height="50"></canvas>
<canvas id="Canvas2" width="50" height="50"></canvas>
```